# Can I add numbers using JavaScript Closures?

Tags: javascript, closures

How can I create a closure function, that sums all passed arguments, like *this*?

```
Add(2)(2) //4
Add(2)(2)(3) // 7
Add(3)(2)(3)(0) // 8


function Add(number){
  return function(number1){
    return function(number2){
      return  number+number1+number2;
    }
  }
}
alert(Add(2)(2)(2));
```

I wanted a generalized way to achieve this.

Comment: It's impossible. The result cannot be both a number and a function

Comment: I don't think so. Whilst your example is correct, I don't think you can programmatically nest functions. I'd love to see an actual solution to this.

Comment: @PavanTiwari Sure, if the number of arguments is fixed, your example is a valid solution. But it cannot have a variable number of arguments. I.e. if Add(2)(2) is 4, then Add(2)(2)(2) is a type error, because you cannot call the number 4 as a function. So either And(2)(2) is 4, or Add(2)(2)(2) is 6, but not both

Comment: The thing you are asking for, is what otherwise qualifies for a "Syntax Error", which will be reported as "Object Expected" error. There's no such syntax in JavaScript and instruction like "Add()()() is in direct violation of a function call and arguments definition.
It is better to clearly describe the aim and the task you are after rather than how would you would prefer the language should be. 
It's a sequential call to function return as Niklas B made clear, cannot return both: a function result and function itself at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are duplicates here, probably with better examples, but I can't find one right now. You need to create a closure to keep track of the sum, then return the *add* function. Give it *valueOf* and *toString* methods so it works in other operations:

```js
var add = (function() {
  var sum = 0;
  function add(n) {
    sum += +n || 0;
    return add;
  }
  add.valueOf = function(){
    return sum;
  }
  add.toString = valueOf;
  return add;
}());

document.write(add(1)(2)(3)(-2)); // 4

document.write('<br>' + add(2)(1) * 2); // 14

document.write('<br>' + add( -add())); // 0
```

Comment: Nice use (abuse) of valueOf and toString!